# How do I evaluate this equation in z3 for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, z3, z3py

I'm trying to evaluate a simple absolute value inequality like this using z3.

```
x = Int("x")
y = Int("y")


def abs(x):
    return If(x >= 0,x,-x)

solve(abs( x / 1000 - y / 1000  ) < .01, y==1000)
```

The output is no solution every time.  I know this is mathematically possible, I just can't figure out how z3 does stuff like this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common gotcha in z3py bindings. Constants are "promoted" to fit into the right type, following the usual Python methodology. But more often than not, it ends up doing the wrong conversion, and you end up with a very confusing situation.

Since your variables `x` and `y` are `Int` values, the comparison against `.01` forces that constant to be `0` to fit the types, and that's definitely not what you wanted to say. The general advice is simply not to mix-and-match arithmetic like this: Cast this as a problem over real-values, not integers. (In general SMTLib doesn't allow mixing-and-matching types in numbers, though z3py does. I think that's misguided, but that's a different discussion.)

To address your issue, the simplest thing to do would be to wrap `0.01` into a real-constant, making the z3py bindings interpret it correctly. So, you'll have:

```py
from z3 import *

x = Int("x")
y = Int("y")

def abs(x):
    return If(x >= 0,x,-x)

solve(abs( x / 1000 - y / 1000  ) < RealVal(.01), y==1000)
```

Note the use of `RealVal`. This returns:

```
[x = 1000, y = 1000]
```

I guess this is what you are after.

But I'd, in general, recommend against using conversions like this. Instead, be very explicit yourself, and cast this as a problem, for instance, over Real values. Note that your division `/ 1000` is also interpreted in this equation as an integer division, i.e., one that produces an integer result. So, I'm guessing this isn't really what you want either. But I hope this gets you started on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

`Int('a') < 0.01` is turned (rightly or wrongly) into `Int('a') < 0` and clearly the absolute value can never be smaller than 0.

I believe you want `Int('a') <= 0` here.

Examples:

```
solve(Int('a') < 0.01, Int('a') > -1)
```

> `no solution`

```
solve(Int('a') <= 0.01, Int('a') > -1)
```

> `[a = 0]`

```
Int('a') < 0.01
```

> `a < 0`